# axios.post not working with firebase auth REST API, react native

Tags: firebase, axios, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to use the firebase auth REST API as authentication system for my react native app. When i try to make a new user by sending a post request using axios.post, it gives me an error with error code 400.

I'll give the functions in my app that pertain to this issue

createUser()

```js
import axios from "axios";

export async function createUser(email, password) {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyCyCKir_y6g4fQeLPFJxDB6oauO7JnPPT0",
    {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      returnSecureToken: true,
    }
  );
}
```

my sign up handler

```js
const signupHandler = async () => {
  setIsAuthenticating(true);
  try {
    await createUser("dekeji2gmail.com", "passwords");
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }
};
```

I do suspect there is no issue with the code itself but some issue with access or something. Please i would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What is the actual response body? Try changing your error logging to... `console.error(error.response?.data ?? error.toJSON())`

Comment: I'm going to guess it says the email is invalid because you have omitted the `@` character

Comment: aye that worked, thanks bruv. Didn't think of that cuz i was getting error 400 since even before i was hardcoding the email and password in.

Comment: and okay i will change my error logging, thanks a lot bro, was also wondering how to best log the error

Comment: Yeah, Axios' default error object is pretty useless. All you really need is the response status and body.

Comment: it doesnt even give the info you need to know what's wrong